# TableDefs.Connect missing semicolon: "ODBCDRIVER=" instead of "ODBC;DRIVER="

Tags: vba, ms-access, connection-string

Just noticed this morning that when I try to get the connection string from a SQL Server linked table in VBA, it starts with "ODBCDRIVER=" instead of "ODBC;DRIVER=". I am getting the string from a current linked table to use as the connection string for a QueryDef in VBA. The missing semicolon causes the code with the QueryDef to raise error 3305: Invalid connection string in pass-through query.

Here is my function to return the connection string. It was returning a valid connection string previously and (as far as I remember) I hadn't made any changes.

```
Public Function GetObjectConnectString(ObjectName As String, ObjectType As String) As String

    GetObjectConnectString = vbNullString
    
    Dim ConnectString As String
    
    Select Case ObjectType
        Case "Table"
            ConnectString = db.TableDefs(ObjectName).Connect
        Case "Query"
            ConnectString = db.QueryDefs(ObjectName).Connect
    End Select
    
    GetObjectConnectString = ConnectString
    
End Function
```

Is this expected behavior and I just need to handle this response by adding in the semicolon?

Using:
Microsoft Access for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2312 Build 16.0.17126.20078) 64-bit
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1 Version 1131

Edit

Here is the db function:

```
Private my_db As DAO.Database

Public Function db() As DAO.Database
    Set db = my_db

ErrEx.Catch 91, 3420 'no longer set
    Set my_db = CurrentDb
    Resume 

End Function
```

I tried reinstalling office but am getting same result.
[image]

Comment: db is a function that returns the CurrentDb, or rather a dao.database object set to CurrentDb

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. My `.Connect` shows string with semicolon.

Comment: I wonder if my office installation is corrupted. Trying an uninstall & reinstall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have updated your MS Access and you are on version 2312. That is the reason! There is a bug in the update released by Microsoft which messed up the connection string as you noticed. A new update fixing the issue is expected to be released by Microsoft soon. See this link for more info:

https://www.accessforever.org/post/missing-semicolon-in-odbc-connect